# Load PHP via Ajax in fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fancybox

The following code display a page loaded with ajax when the page is loaded. However, I don't know how to load PHP within the ajax file. Can anyone help please?

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
// call fancybox
function openFancy(){ 
setTimeout( function() {$('.fancybox').trigger('click'); },0); 
} 
// create cookie on button click
function dontShow(){
 $.fancybox.close(); // optional
 $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 30 }); // expiration in 30 days
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited'); // create cookie 'visited' with no value
    if (visited == 'yes') {
    return false;
   } else {
    openFancy(); // cookie has no value so launch fancybox on page load
}
 $('.fancybox').fancybox({
  scrolling : 'no',
  width : '100%',
  fitToView : true,
  closeBtn : false,
  padding : 0,
  margin : 20,
  locked : false,
  scrollOutside : false,
  closeClick  : false, 
    helpers     : { overlay : {
        closeClick: false,
        locked: true},
         }
        });
}); // ready
/* ]]> */
```

Comment: What do you mean load php? `$('#something').load('something.php');`?

Comment: I don't understand your question too

Comment: Sorry if that was a bit vague. I'm using fancybox to load a php file on page load via ajax. The php script in the overlay.php file I'm loading via ajax doesn't work. '<a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="overlay.php"></a>' How do I enable the php script to load as it should?

Comment: Still unclear what you want to do. What is the expected result from overlay.php? does it work outside fancybox?

Comment: Yes overload.php works outside fancybox. If I take out all the php scripts in this file, leaving just html it works. As soon as I add a simple php script, such as <?php bloginfo('url'); ?>. It breaks fancybox. I just need to be able to load php within this file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

For the link (HTML)

```
<a id="fancybox_ajax" href="overlay.php"></a>
```

For the fancybox's setup:(JS)

```
$("#fancybox_ajax").fancybox({
         scrolling : 'no',
         width : '100%',
         fitToView : true,
         closeBtn : false,
         padding : 0,
         margin : 20,
         locked : false,
         scrollOutside : false,
         closeClick  : false, 
         helpers     : { overlay : {
                               closeClick: false,
                               locked: true},
                        },
        //This is what you have to add
         ajax : {
            type    : "POST",
                //This is optional if you want to pass some data
                data    : 'key=value'
         }
    });
```

Good luck! ^^

Comment: Thanks for you reply but that doesn't work unfortunately. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to this. Can anyone help at all? To reiterate, I'm trying to load a php file via ajax in this fancybox script. overlay.php works fine outside fancybox and fancybox works if I only use html in the file. As soon as I add a simple PHP script, I get the error 'The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.'